# word for telling the truth/ lying and then regretting it?

Tags: single-word-requests

My brother once asked me if there was a word for telling the truth and then strongly regretting it, and when i looked on the internet, i couldn't find one... so i decided to ask on here. I then began to think more, and wondered that if there was a word for telling the truth and then strongly regretting it, was there a word for lying and then strongly regretting it? or was there a word for one and not the other... or a word that could describe both? i do mean strongly and sincerely regret, might i add, rather than to just have second thoughts.

Comment: Having second thoughts?

Comment: When you ask a question on a site for ["serious English language enthusiasts,"](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour), you really should expend that extra effort and capitalize the word "i" in your question – especially when it shows up three times in one sentence.

Comment: If you regret saying something, you *wish to recant* it.

Comment: @WS2 haha or just plain 'regret'

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of a single word to replace *'I regret what I said'* or *'I shouldn't have said that'*.

There is a phrase: **know when to keep your mouth shut**.

Truth or lie, you wish you'd *just kept your mouth shut*. Then you wouldn't be in this mess.

Answer (score 0):

That is when you ***put your foot in your mouth.***  If you're aware of the indecorum to the extent you describe, you're ***mortified***.

I'm unaware of a term which captures in a single word the mortification that comes from specifically having put one's foot in one's mouth.