# equivalent to 'chop my tongue off now'?

Tags: idiom-requests

'Chop my tongue off now', when you regret saying something badly and it hurt the person badly too. It's usually said directly after you've just after realising belatedly how hurtful or wrong it was.

Comment: Figuratively, anglophones *bite their tongue* ***before*** saying the wrong thing (figuratively immobilize the tongue so you can't speak). Said ***afterwards***, there's *Wash my mouth out [with soap]*, but that's usually in response to having used profanity ("dirty" words), not regret at having hurt someone.

Comment: Related: [word for telling the truth/lying and then regretting it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252310/word-for-telling-the-truth-lying-and-then-regretting-it)

Answer (score 3):

The expression "Sorry - Chop my tongue off" is very expressive and would be understood even though it is not an English idiom.

Others that come to mind:

**Kill me now.**

This is more general. It is mostly said to a friend when something very embarrassing has been said or is happening. Here's how it might be used in your case.

> Kill me now - I shouldn't have said that.

**I should bite my tongue off**, e.g.

> *I should bite my tongue off right now ...*
>
> The Host By Meyer, Stephenie

Note, this is not frequently used.

Comment: +1 for "kill me now". Related to that sentiment is the concept "mortified". This means "ashamed to death". Which is why "kill me now" is so appropriate. "I am so ashamed of what I just said, that I could die. I'm mortified. Kill me now."

Comment: I think your Meyer cite is just a slight twist on standard *bite my tongue = keep silent*, since the speaker hasn't *yet* said whatever is likely to "ruin everything else".

Comment: @vladkornea: *I'm [truly] mortified* is a pretty common "abject apology" for OP's context. *Kill me now* is easily understood, but wouldn't be one tenth as common, I'm sure.

Comment: While *kill me now* might work, it is often said by someone who is exasperated by the conduct of another, often jokingly by a parent to a child doing something that brings distress. Similarly *just take me out (back) and shoot me!*

Comment: Plus one for *sorry*.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the idiom, **"to put your foot in your mouth"** meaning that you've said something regrettable that hurt or embarrassed either yourself or someone else.

More information [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+foot+in+it).

Comment: Adapted to the OP's question:  "Let me take my foot out of my mouth."

Answer (score 0):

"Well, shut my mouth" is definitely an expression that I have heard in SE U.S.

Sometimes accompanied by "...and call me _______ ."